# Why the code provides the odd number from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

could you please help me understand why the following line result is `[1,3]`?

```
[1,3,6].filter( item => item % 2)
```

I was expecting to receive the even number from the array.

Many thanks!

Comment: [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) expects a boolean to be returned from the passed callback and will evaluate any returned value as such. The [remainder operator (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) returns the remainder after dividing by the passed number (in this case 2). When the `item` is even, the remainder is `0` which `filter()` evaluates as [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and so doesn't include that element in the result.

Comment: For clarity, you may wish to indicate explicitly what you want the remainder to be. `filter(item => item % 2 == 0)` will pick even numbers. `filter(item => item % 2 == 1)` will pick odd numbers.

Comment: Many thanks for your responses!

I am new to JavaScript and trying to understand the logic of the difference between these examples and it's results:

[0,true,'Boo'].filter( item => item)
Result is: [true, 'Boo']

[1,3,6].filter( item => item % 2)
Result is: [1,3]

Answer (score 0):

Filter checks for a boolean, 3 % 2 is equal to 1, which evaluates to true.

You want `item % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Even numbers are those numbers that are exactly divisible by **2**.

The remainder operator **%** gives the remainder when used with a number. For **example**,

```
const number = 6;
const result = number % 4; // 2
```

Hence, when **%** is used with **2**, the number is even if the remainder is **zero**. Otherwise, the number is **odd**.

```
// program to check if the number is even or odd
// take input from the user
const number = prompt("Enter a number: ");

//check if the number is **even**
if(number % 2 == 0) {
    console.log("The number is even.");
}

// if the number is **odd**
else {
    console.log("The number is odd.");
}
```

ref : https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/even-odd